# Convergence of sequence $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n^2+2}{2x_{n}-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

I got a problem as follows, I have stucked for a week and I got no progress... May I recieve some guidance?

Define a sequence $\{x_n\}$ by $x_1=c$ and $\displaystyle x_{n+1}=\frac{x_{n}^{2}+2}{2x_n - 1}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, where $c\neq \frac{1}{2}$ is a constant.

Prove that $\{x_n\}$ is convergent and find its limit.

(Hint: Consider $\displaystyle c>\frac{1}{2}$ and $\displaystyle c<\frac{1}{2}$ separately.)

I can kind of guess $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n = 2$, and find the recurrence relationship between $|x_{n+1} - 2|$ and $|x_n - 2|$,
but I failed to proceed. Nevertheless, I tried with the Cauchy convergence criterion by considering $|x_{n+1} - x_n|$ and I end up with nothing.

Thank you in advance for your kind reply.

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, but, have you tried to find the fixed point?

Comment: Have you tried if it is monotonic?

Comment: I've seen this method work for questions like these: Determine when $x_{n+1} - x_n$ is positive and when negative. For different ranges of $c$, try to bound $x_{n+1}$ between $x_n$ and a fixed point, maybe using induction.

Comment: If $c < \frac12$ then $x_{n+1} < 0$ for all $n$ so it can't converge to $2$. If a limit exists then it satisfies $L=\frac{L^2+2}{2L-1}$ which is a quadratic equation. Solve for $L$ and consider the roots. Once you've found the limits try to prove the two cases separately.

Comment: To give a context for this: the above recursion is Newton's method for zeros of $f(x)=x^2-x-2=(x-1)(x+2)$. So the problem amounts to showing that Newton's method converges to one of the two roots if $c\neq 1/2$, and which root is obtained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $g$ denote a possible  limit of the sequence $x_n.$ Then $$g={g^2+2\over 2g-1}$$ Hence $g=2$ or $g=-1.$

Consider the case $c>{1\over 2}.$ Assume $x_n>{1\over 2}.$ Then $x_{n+1}>2.$ Indeed $${x_n^2+2\over 2x_n-1}-2={(x_n-2)^2\over 2x_n-1}>0$$ Moreover $x_{n+1}<x_n,$ as $${x_n^2+2\over 2x_n-1}-x_n=-{(x_n-2)(x_n+1)\over 2x_n-1} \ (*)$$ Therefore the sequence $x_n$ is decreasing and bounded below by $2$ for $n\ge 2.$ Hence $x_n$ is convergent and $g=2.$

Let $c<{1\over 2}.$ By the similar procedure based on   the formula $${x_n^2+2\over 2x_n-1}+1={(x_n+1)^2\over 2x_n-1}$$ and on $(*)$ we can prove that  $x_n<-1,$ $x_{n+1}>x_n$ for $n\ge 2$ and the limit is equal $-1.$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, the approach works and I divided cases into $c>\frac{1}{2}$, $-1<c<\frac{1}{2}$ and $c\leq -1$. Previously I stuck with the division and now I figured it out. :(

Answer (score 5):

Let $\,2 x_n - 1 = u_n \,$, then substituting $\,x_n = \dfrac{u_n+1}{2}\,$ in the original recurrence gives:

$$
\frac{u_{n+1}+1}{2} = \frac{u_n^2 + 2 u_n + 9}{4u_n} \quad\iff\quad u_{n+1} = \frac{u_n^2 + 9}{2u_n} \tag{1}
$$

Substituting $\,u_n = 3v_n\,$ in $\,(1)\,$ gives:
$$
3v_{n+1} = \frac{9 v_n^2 + 9}{2 \cdot 3 v_n} = \frac{3}{2}\,\frac{v_n^2 + 1}{v_n}
\quad\iff\quad v_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}\left(v_n + \frac{1}{v_n}\right) \tag{2}
$$

Then:

$$
\frac{v_{n+1}-1}{v_{n+1}+1} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}\left(v_n + \frac{1}{v_n}\right)-1}{\frac{1}{2}\left(v_n + \frac{1}{v_n}\right)+1} = \frac{v_n^2 - 2 v_n + 1}{v_n^2 + 2 v_n + 1} = \left(\frac{v_n-1}{v_n+1}\right)^2 = \ldots = \left(\frac{v_1 - 1}{v_1 + 1}\right)^{2^n}
$$

Comment: One cute but boutique way to amplify the last point is to substitute $v_n=\coth \gamma_n$. Then the final line can be cast as $e^{-2\gamma_{n+1}}=e^{-4\gamma_{n}}$, i.e., the value of $\gamma_n$ doubles on each step.

Comment: @Semiclassical Right, thanks for pointing it out, that's a neat observation.

Answer (score 3):

This is NOT an answer, just some analysis

Take the subtraction:

$$x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{-(x_n-2)(x_n+1)}{2x_n-1}$$

If we make an analogy with the autonomous differential equation,
$$x'=f(x)=\frac{-(x-2)(x+1)}{2x-1}$$

we can see there are three critical points, where $x=-1$ and $x=2$ are stable, $x=\frac{1}2$ is a saddle point.

If intial value $x_0>\frac{1}2$ it will converges to $2$, and if initial value $x_0<\frac{1}2$, it will converge to $-1$.